# How can I do to see the input in my alert box?

Tags: reactjs

I have that code :

```
const App = () => {
  const [place, setplace] = useState("")

  const test = (place) => {
    alert(place)
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Container fluid>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
      <Nav
        className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0"
        style={{ maxHeight: '100px' }}
        navbarScroll
      >
      </Nav>
      <Form className="d-flex">
        <FormControl
          type="search"
          placeholder="Lieu"
          className="me-2"
          aria-label="Search"
        />
        <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={() => test(place)}>Search</Button>
      </Form>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My problem is when I click on the button I have nothing in the alert box whereas I would like to see in the alert box waht I typed in the FormControl.

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `onChange` to your form control, and then call your function, also, since you are using the state, no need to pass it as a param.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-flower-z671i?file=/src/App.js)

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("Hi");

  const showAlert = useCallback(() => {
    alert(state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(e.target.value);

          setState(e.target.value);
        }}
      />

      <button onClick={showAlert}>Show Alert</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you don't have anything changing the value of 'place', so you're always going to have a null value passed into test().

What you need to do is add an onChange event to your FormControl that updates your state with the entered value.

```
const App = () => {
  const [place, setplace] = useState("")

  const test = (place) => {
    alert(place)
}

  // new
  handleChange = (event) => {
    setplace(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Container fluid>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
      <Nav
        className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0"
        style={{ maxHeight: '100px' }}
        navbarScroll
      >
      </Nav>
      <Form className="d-flex">
        <FormControl
          type="search"
          placeholder="Lieu"
          className="me-2"
          aria-label="Search"
          onChange=this.handleChange // new
        />
        <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={() => test(place)}>Search</Button>
      </Form>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I haven't actually used React in a while, so my syntax might be a bit off, but this should be a good place to start at least.